# Mysql select count optimisation

Tags: mysql

How can I optimise this query?

```
select count(p.products_id) as total 
from products_to_categories pc,
    products p
where pc.categories_id = 20
    and p.products_status = 1
    and p.products_id = pc.products_id";
```

Comment: Optimize how? For what? Assuming you mean for speed, memory, or read efficiency, you need to post your table structure, including indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query with proper explicit `join` syntax:

```
select count(p.products_id) as total 
from products_to_categories pc join
     products p
     on p.products_id = pc.products_id
where pc.categories_id = 20 and p.products_status = 1;
```

There are two reasonable possible execution plans for the query.  The first is to filter on `products` by `products_status` and then do the `join` and aggregation.  The second is to filter on the other table by `categories_id` and then do the `join` and aggregation.

You should try adding the following indexes for the first approach:

```
products(products_status, products_id);
products_to_categories(products_id, categories_id);
```

For the second approach, try these indexes:

```
products_to_categories(categories_id, products_id);
products(products_id, products_status);
```